# Issue with getting Jenkins to download all files from github

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have jenkins (version 2.32.2) integrated with github and am using the github organization folder plugin. I'm able to scan the organization successfully but jenkins has only downloaded some of the files from the github repo and is not downloading new files when I re-scan.

Below are the files that jenkins has downloaded. These are only some of the files from the github repo (in particular package.json is missing), and the update date is Mar 11th even though multiple successful scans have been run since then.
[image: ls from jenkins build directory]

These are the files that are in the github branch that jenkins is pointing to (package.json is there):

[image]

How do I force jenkins to download the latest files?

Update: 
Here's the contents of the Jenkinsfile

```
node('master') {

    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

    try {

       stage 'Test'

            env.NODE_ENV = "test"

            print "Environment will be : ${env.NODE_ENV}"

            sh 'node -v'
            sh 'npm prune'
            sh 'npm install'
            sh 'npm test'
    }
    catch (err) {

        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

            /*mail body: "project build error is here: ${env.BUILD_URL}" ,
            from: 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
            replyTo: 'yyyy@yyyy.com',
            subject: 'project build failed',
            to: 'opike99@gmail.com'*/

        throw err
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `Jenkinsfile` look like? What happens if you replay a build with `node { checkout scm; sh 'pwd; git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD; git rev-parse HEAD; ls -l' }`? Do you see the same directory that you're inspecting in your screenshot above? Are the branch name and commit ID as you expect?

Comment: Provided the Jenkinsfile. Give me a little bit of time to look into your other suggestion and questions.

Comment: I'd say you're not calling `checkout scm`, so the code isn't being checked out. Presumably you previously did have that in the `Jenkinsfile`, so now you're left with that old checkout.

Comment: The way the Jenkinsfile got on to the jenkins server in the first place was by pulling it from github, so there wasn't even a Jenkinsfile at all prior to the very first checkout. The github jenkins plugin must have handled the first checkout.

Comment: which begs the question - if the Jenkinsfile is responsible for doing the checkout, how do updates in the Jenkinsfile itself that were pushed to github get handled?

Comment: The Git(Hub) branch source plugin checks the repo separate from the workspace to fetch the Jenkinsfile — it doesn't check out the whole repo to fetch that one file.

Comment: Does it only look for the Jenkinsfile? Empirically, that's not what I saw. There were other files downloaded on to the jenkins server besides that one file.